# How to create a timestamp in google sheets when a linked formula changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently creating a google sheet where I have linked figures from other sheets (importrange) in a control spreadsheet and I want to know when the other documents have been updated.

I need a script that will be able to tell that the figure in the cell (with a formula in and not manual entry) has changed.

I have found scripts that update when the cell has a manual entry into it, but not one that will be able to tell when the figure created by the formula has changed

Here is a [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kShkFStV9H0Pse9G0uSQfpM-csu8kAuG6zDRxfZAxmg/edit?usp=sharing) to my dummy sheet where I testing it out

I have added comments on there to explain things

Comment: Hello! Could you provide a sample sheet and show us what you have already tried?

Comment: I have added a link to the file

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of this in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite). In this case it adds a comment to the cell saying when the cell was changed.

Comment: Would you say this is the only way? I would preferably want it captured in a cell

Comment: @AshleySkrewfaceHowell no, you could replace the part where it adds a comment to output a value into a cell.

Answer (score 0):

`onEdit` **doesn't work** when a linked formulae changes.

The only way I see is instead of using `IMPORTRANGE`, you can use apps script as web app to trigger a "GET" request and then capture the changes to the new sheet with the timestamp.